# FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException vs FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException when user account is disabled?

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am currently developing a android app which uses FirebaseAuth to control users.
The users can sign-in either using email or Google.

Considering this, i am catching some exceptions in order to handle any problems with the authentication system.

Most of these work fine. This is my code:

```
    when(task.exception!!){
        is FirebaseAuthEmailException -> {
            errorDialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.exception_email_title)
            errorDialogBuilder.setMessage(getString(R.string.exception_email_msg, task.exception!!.localizedMessage))
        }
        is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException -> {
            errorDialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.exception_invalid_credentials_title)
            errorDialogBuilder.setMessage(getString(R.string.exception_invalid_credentials_msg, task.exception!!.localizedMessage))
        }
        is FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException -> {
            val invalidUserException = task.exception!! as FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException
            when (invalidUserException.errorCode) {
                "ERROR_USER_DISABLED" -> {
                    errorDialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.exception_user_disabled_title)
                    errorDialogBuilder.setMessage(R.string.exception_user_disabled_msg)
                    errorDialogBuilder.setNeutralButton(R.string.more, null)
                }
                "ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND" -> {
                    errorDialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.exception_user_not_found_title)
                    errorDialogBuilder.setMessage(getString(R.string.exception_user_not_found_msg, fragmentView.email_input_signin.text.toString()))
                    errorDialogBuilder.setNeutralButton(R.string.action_createnew_account) { _, _ ->
                        viewModel.createUser(fragmentView.email_input_signin.text.toString(), fragmentView.email_password.text.toString())
                    }
                }
                else -> {
                    errorDialogBuilder.setTitle(invalidUserException.errorCode)
                    errorDialogBuilder.setMessage(invalidUserException.localizedMessage)

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I had no problems when using this code for development purposes. But I found out something very weird:
I am playing around with disabling users; This issue ocurred: Whenever I disable a google account, **not** a `FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException` is thrown with code `ERROR_USER_DISABLED` as when trying to sign in with a disabled email-based account, but a `FirebaseUserCollissionException` which has the exact same message as a `FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException` with code `ERROR_USER_DISABLED`:

```
com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException: The user account has been disabled by an administrator.
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdx.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.1.0:42)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzfa.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.1.0:19)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzet.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.1.0:34)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzev.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.1.0:98)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzev.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.1.0:85)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzed.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.1.0:43)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zza.onTransact(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.1.0:13)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)
```

This is how it looks normally, when trying to use an disabled email-based account(this is handled&this works):

```
com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException: The user account has been disabled by an administrator.
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdx.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.1.0:6)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzfa.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.1.0:21)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzet.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.1.0:34)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzev.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.1.0:74)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzed.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.1.0:18)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zza.onTransact(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.1.0:13)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)
```

Why are there two different exceptions being used here? And why would firebase throw a `FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException` when the users account is disabled, as, from what i know from the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException), the `FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException` is only thrown when there are user accounts conflicting?

**In addition:**
Brief extract from the firebase docs:

> ### FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException
>
> *public final class **FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException** extends **FirebaseAuthException***
>
> Thrown when an operation on a FirebaseUser instance couldn't be
>   completed due to a conflict with another existing user.

Answer (score 0):

That's weird. I read the Google API for Android docs - and what you said was correct - `FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException` should only be thrown when there is a conflict between Firebase users, particularly if both share the same credential accidentally, but I think Firebase Auth does not allow that and it can detect if the credential between two users or more are similar right from the start.

I think that Firebase Auth tries to re-register/re-add the disabled Google account into the system when you use it to sign in. Since the Google account is disabled, Firebase Auth may consider the account invalid - yet the account still remain and recorded in the auth system - hence if you are trying to sign in with the previously disabled Google account, Firebase Auth tries to re-add that and collide with the previous record of disabled Google account.

There is also a chance that this may be a bug/glitch/error in Firebase Auth side.

If you are asking about difference, I think it's more to the circumstances/conditions that caused either of those exceptions to occur; most exceptions are similar, it is the purpose and cause of error that makes the difference.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your extended answer. I will see if this is the problem in my case and I will come back to you later.

Comment: Good luck! If you need anything, just let me know.